# Garchfit in R called from Julia: Multivariate data inputs require lhs for the formula

Tags: r, julia, fgarch, rcall

I'm trying to call the R function garchFit from Julia using Rcall.  When I do things directly in R, all is well: the following works

```
    library("fGarch")
    library("rugarch")
    spxData <- read.csv(file = 'SPXlogreturns.csv')
    y = spxData$y
    fit.arch <- garchFit(~garch(1,0),data=y,trace=F,include.mean=FALSE)
```

But when I have the same vector of log returns in Julia and try to do the same thing using RCall:

```
    using RCall
    @rput y
    R"""
    library("fGarch")
    library("rugarch")
    fit.arch <- garchFit(~garch(1,0),data=y,trace=F,include.mean=FALSE)
    """
```

I get the error *Multivariate data inputs require lhs for the formula*. Yet when I @rget y back from R, it's a vector, so I don't understand what garchFit wants.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: how did you assign y in the Julia version?

Comment: data = readdlm(string(pathn,"SPXlogreturns.csv"),',') y = data[:,4] The key point is that y in Julia is a vector too, and is exactly the same as the y in the R example.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone googles it and has a similar problem, the answer is that you need to unlist.  For no (at least to me) readily obvious reason, @rput creates a list in R, not a vector.  So the answer is

`using RCall
@rput y
R"""
library("fGarch")
library("rugarch")
yy <- unlist(y)
fit.arch <- garchFit(~garch(1,0),data=yy,trace=F,include.mean=FALSE)
"""`